# Zend db with prepared statement doesn't fetch all data

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, zend-db

#### First the guilty code:

```
$preparedGetData = $db->prepare("CALL getData(?)");
foreach($userSet as $r) {
    $preparedGetData->execute(array($r['id_user']));
    $rs = $preparedGetData->fetchAll();
    $preparedGetData->closeCursor();
}
```

#### Explication

`getData` = stored procedure in mysql
`$db` = instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql (using Zend version 1.10.0 )

#### Symptoms

- When I leave out `closeCursor` in the second cycle I already get error:

  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
- But I am using `fetchAll` !!!
- When I add the `closeCursor` the result arrives incomplete. Invoking `CALL getData('3872')` in query browser returns 1 row with 72 columns. The same done by the code above returns 1 row with only first 41 columns.

**What I'm doing wrong?**

### Edit2: Semi-solution

#### Code updated to:

```
$preparedGetData = $db->prepare("CALL getData(?)");
foreach($userSet as $r) {
    $preparedGetData->execute(array($r['id_user']));

    $rs=array();

    do {
        try {
            $partial_rowset = $preparedGetData->fetchAll(); // When I put fetchAll() after the end of the cycle, I get empty resultset.
        } catch (PDOException $error) { // The PDOException doesn't get caught here. Why?
            error_log($error);
        } catch (Exception $error) { 
            error_log($error);
        }
        if ($partial_rowset) {
            $rs=array_merge($rs,$partial_rowset);
        }
    } while ($preparedGetData->nextRowset());
}
```

#### Symptoms

- Getting error:
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
  Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in /home/GIT/includes/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:294
  on the line with `fetchAll`.
- This error I can catch using generic exception.
- With this code I get all 72 columns.
- I perceive this nasty because I am deliberately catching generic exception and just turning it into log. Which I guess will also become an performance issue (the cycle runs about 10 000 times).

Comment: I seem to remember a bug about stored procedures & trailing status... Does it chance if you call `$preparedGetData->nextRowset()` after `->fetchAll()`? What happens if you test this with pure `PDO` for the time being, does the problem still occur or is it in the `Zend` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL stored procedures *may* have multiple result sets. That is, you can run more than one SELECT query inside a stored procedure, and then iterate over these multiple result sets.

This complicates fetching because the whole result is really like an array of arrays of arrays (multiple result sets, each result set may have multiple rows, each row may have multiple columns).

But `fetchAll()` only fetches all the rows from *one* result set. So when you call a stored procedure, you need to force it to flush all result sets. That is, keep calling `nextRowset()` until that function returns null.

The Zend_Db API is modeled off of PDO, so you can see example usage of `nextRowset()` in the docs for [`PDOStatement::nextRowset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php).

Unfortunately, there is no such function like `fetchAllRowsets()`. You are left to do it yourself as a while loop.

Comment: Yes, nextRowset() is returning `true` for several times. But following the do-while example from the documentation right at second pass I get *PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error' in ...* on the line with fetch_all. Any idea why?

Comment: FYI:[possibly related bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=41997) (should be fixed, but recently reopened)

Comment: @Wrikken : Yeah that might be it. I'll wait if they fix it and then try to remove the protected block. So far unfortunately I cannot use php 5.5 because [php5-json breaks firephp](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87067/package-php5-json-breaks-firephp)

Comment: @sumid: if you use `mysql` as a driver, can you switch to `mysqlnd`? There seem to be less problems with that.

Comment: @Wrikken : I tried both. Makes no difference in this issue :-(